# If condition in calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a small problem to solve and I hope you guys can solve it easily.
So currently I have a calculated column which calculates the value but only when the status is available, so it looks like this
IF(Status="available",=SUM([column1]-[column2])
Now what I want is to check as on or condition if it the status is consumed too. So it can work for both the status properly. 
Please respond if you know how to do this !
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then these two formulas should do the trick:

```
=IF(Status="available",column1+column2,IF(Status="consumed",column1+column2))

=IF(OR(Status="available",Status="consumed"),column1+column2)
```